# Behaviour of Regular List passed into Process Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am just wondering why a regular list that is passed into a process as an argument (and modified in the process) doesn't remain as a pass by reference as if I had passed it into a function normally?

The following is some example code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def appendThings(x):
    x.append(1)
    x.append(2)
    x.append(3)

x = []
p = Process(target=appendThings, args=(x))
p.start()
p.join()
print(x)
```

I expected to see:

```
[1,2,3]
```

but instead got:

```
[]
```

General insight into multiprocessing is welcome too as I am currently learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing can not pass python objects directly.  The arguments sent to the Process are a copy.

You have at least a couple of options to return data:

1. Shared [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)
2. [multiprocessing.Manager()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers)

A working example using the manager:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def append_things(x):
    x.append(1)
    x.append(2)
    x.append(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Manager().list([])
    p = Process(target=append_things, args=(x,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen!! That the arguments are sent as a copy was what I was after

Answer (score 3):

**Two things you should note:**

1. You should not terminate the process by p.terminate(). That would just terminate the process before it can run its course.

The following is some example code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def appendThings(x):
        x.append(1)
        x.append(2)
        x.append(3)
        print ("I reached here!")

x = []
p = Process(target=appendThings, args=(x,))
p.start()
p.terminate()
p.join()
print(x)
```

It will output only the following:

```
[]
```

---

2. Process don't share memory by themselves.

So if you do the following:

```
def appendThings(x):
    x.append(1)
    x.append(2)
    x.append(3)
print (x)
```

It will print:

```
[1,2,3]
```

So in multiprocessing you should use Manager to share the objects between processes. A manager returned by Manager() will support types list, dict, Namespace, Lock, RLock, Semaphore, BoundedSemaphore, Condition, Event, Queue, Value and Array. You can read more about Manager() from the [Python Official Doco.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

**Finally you should modify your code as follows to make it do what you intended:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def appendThings(x):
    x.append(1)
    x.append(2)
    x.append(3)

x = Manager().list()
#x =list()
p = Process(target=appendThings, args=(x,))
p.start()
p.join()
print(x)
```

So the output will be:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for that... yep, was a bit of a facepalmer with the terminate line (wasn't in my actual code).